# Execute class's object in if-statement python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

i'm a python fresher. I have a problem and want to ask for the answers.
there is my class :

```
class DoSomethingWithList :

    def inputList(self, parameter_list):
       ...

    def deleteSomething(self):
       ...
```

and the rest of

```
temp = 0

while temp == 0 :

selection = input('input selection: ')
list1 = DoSomethingWithList()

if selection == 1 :  
    RangeOfList = int(input('input range of list : '))
    list1.inputList(RangeOfList) # this is not executed
elif selection == 2 :
    list1.deleteSomething()      # and this too
else : 
    temp = 1
```

this code looped forever. list1 objects aren't performed. I cant see the problem here.Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. But note, `input` will always return `str` objects, which are never equal to `int` objects.

Comment: oh thanks for your help, now i got it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input function reads a string rather than a number. you should change the if conditional from 'selection == 1' to 'selection == "1"' like highlighted below

```
selection = input('input selection: ')
list1 = DoSomethingWithList()

if selection == "1" : 
  RangeOfList = int(input('input range of list : '))
  list1.inputList(RangeOfList) # this is not executed
elif **selection == "2" :**
   list1.deleteSomething()      # and this too
else : 
   temp = 1
```